# Issue converting char to int java

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, postfix-notation

I am writing a code that takes a infix expression and converts it to postfix. It then takes the postfix expression and solves it. Converting from infix to postfix works fine, but for some reason my code cannot solve a postfix expression if it contains a 2-digit number or more. Originally it would read 10 2 + and return 3, but with my current code, it reads 10 2 + and spits out 540, so I'm assuming when i go from char to int, i get the ASCII code instead of the actual value. Here is the part of my code where it attempts to read the postfix string, determine what number it has, and put it into the stack for later solving:(Note I am aware the current set up only supports up to 3 digit numbers)

```
LinkedStack<Integer> stack = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            if(i+1 == str.length()) {
                stack.push(Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)));
                break;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1))) {
                char x = str.charAt(i);
                char y = str.charAt(i+1);
                int k = x * 10;
                int m = k + y;
                stack.push(m);
                i++;
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+2))){
                char x = str.charAt(i);
                char y = str.charAt(i+1);
                char z = str.charAt(i+2);
                int k = x * 100;
                int w = y * 10;
                int m = x + y + z;
                stack.push(m);              
                i++;
                i++;
            }
            else{
                stack.push(Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)));
            }
```

Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: consider this code `int i = "2".toCharArray()[0] - '0';
        System.out.println(i);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I actually just found a solution myself, I put it below

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself:

So for example I'll use the if statement if the int should be a 2-digit number(10-99)
instead of :

```
 char x = str.charAt(i);
 char y = str.charAt(i+1);
 int k = x * 10;
 int m = k + y;
 stack.push(m);
 i++;
```

I found that this works instead:

```
int k = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)) * 10;
int m = k + Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i+1));
stack.push(m);
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

*may I suggest a completely different solution*
one line with lambda:

```
LinkedStack<Integer> stack = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
Stream.of( str.split( "\\D" ) ).forEach( s -> stack.push( Integer.parseInt( s ) ) );
```